# NIC can't get IP address/connect all of a sudden

Tags: networking, network-adapter

As the title implies, I'm having NIC issues. Anyways, as of last night it was working perfectly. Then this morning it was having issues, with Windows showing "No Internet Access". I rebooted the computer, the issue the persisted. Then I rebooted the router (the hardware has been sketchy sometimes, so figured that might be it) No success. In order to isolate the issue, I booted onto a Ubuntu Live CD. It couldn't get an address either. I tried assigning a static IP on Linux & Windows but nothing was reachable either.

Windows `ipconfig` returns a 169....etc IP which suggests a DHCP issue. Linux (network-manager) just stated "connecting..." forever when attempting to get an IP.

Not really sure what could've happened, however I'm quite sure it's dead now. I'm wondering if there is anything else I can do? I'd hate to go buy a PCI-e NIC if this thing can be saved!

**EDIT**

Other devices can connect via Wi-Fi & Ethernet. Multiple Ethernet cables have been tried.

Comment: did u try to uninstall and install again the driver from device manager?

Comment: @Botmaster Yes I have.

Comment: do you have another device like cellphone to connect to wifi? does it work?

Comment: Have you tried another ethernet cable?

Comment: See the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manufacturer and model of your network interface controller (NIC). You may be able to get that information from a command line with one of the following commmands:

```
ipconfig /all | find "Description"
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name
```

Then go to the manufacturer's website and look for a driver for the NIC. Often, included with the driver for your operating system will be a diagnostic utility from the manufacturer. If the manufacturer offers a "driver-only" download, don't select that, instead, select the full download option. You may be able to run the diagnostic without installing a new driver and the diagnostic utility can help pinpoint whether there is a hardware problem with the NIC. I.e., if it fails the tests performed by the manufacturer's diagnostic utility, you may need to buy another one. Or there may be an option to reset some parameter for the NIC offered by the utility which may fix the problem.

Comment: It all of a sudden started working, after I did some stuff the manufacturer (realtek) recommended. Had to sodder some stuff, but it's working great now! Turns out something got dislodged in it, causing it to impartially work.

Answer (score 0):

I probably know this isn't what will help narrow down the exact problem, as I would recommend moonpoint's advice for doing that. But something else you could quickly try is making sure you have flushed the DNS cache and, releasing/renewing the IP (which I"m sure you have already done, but figured I would mention it).

open CMD or Terminal

CMD:

Flush dns: "  ipconfig /flushdns   "

IP releasing/renewing: "     ipconfig /release    " and "     ipconfig /renew     "

Terminal: 
link below shows many different ways or kinds of dns flushes for linux based OS.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/

IP releasing/renewing:

sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

or I think I've heard this one works as well

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Good luck! I'm having separate kinds of networking issues. And man, I'm frustrated and tired!! So I feel your pain.